# Execution stored procedure using SqlCommand and SqlParameter is returing System.DbNull object when the response has decimal values

Tags: sql-server, datatable, ado.net, sqlconnection, sqldataadapter

I have method to execute stored procedure which returns the DataTable. When the same SP is executed in management studio, I could see some values. But when filled the SqlDataAdapter object to a DataTable, the value is returning as DbNull.

```
public DataTable ExecuteStoredProc(string procname, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        var dataTable = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            SqlConnection connection;
            using (connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
            {
                var command = new SqlCommand(procname, connection) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure };

                foreach (var par in parameters)
                {
                    command.Parameters.Add(par);
                }

                connection.Open();

                var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                adapter.Fill(dataTable);
                connection.Close();
                adapter.Dispose();
                return dataTable;
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
            return null;
        }

    }
```

When executed in management studio rows are something like

```
    Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4
    1       | abc     | 1       | NULL
    2       | def     | 1       | NULL
    3       | gef     | 1       | 1000.0000
    4       | hij     | 1       | NULL
```

From code when executing the same SP I am getting all the rows, but `Column4` is returned as `System.DbNull` object for *all* of the rows, including row 3. Any insight on this?

Comment: Not sure what the confusion is here. When you run this in SSMS you get NULL and when you run it in dotnet you get NULL.

Comment: `System.DbNull` is the .NET equivalent of null in SQL. What you describe is exactly the expected behaviour.

Comment: The table i have posted is the response when I see in SSMS. But when I do the same thing in C#,  I am getting colum4 as null for all the 4 values. Whereas the 3rd row of the 4th column should have been a decimal. @SeanLange

Comment: Have you checked the parameters at runtime to make certain they are the same? The behavior you are describing indicates there is a difference between them.

Comment: Everything is the same. The issue is when executed via code, it returns null. But SSMS return's properly.

Comment: There is something different. It isn't just going to drop a NULL into a column. Maybe you should run profiler and examine the exact statement being executed. There isn't much anybody can do here because it is going to come down to being able to step through your code and examine values at execution. Your code appears to be ok to me.